# What color should I paint my barred owl house?

Tags: birds, outdoor

I built a barred owl house.

I painted it with an exterior white oil primer initial coat to protect the wood.

I live in the NorthEast.

Do I need to camouflage paint it?  Paint it brown like a tree trunk? Of just leave it white?

NOTE: I am trying to attract a local owl I've seen to use it.

Comment: use dark colors about the same as the trunks.you live in the northeast of what country,lots of countries have a northeast.